# How do I implement view slides

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager

I am particularly new to android development, I have a concept on which I have to work on which is similar to the twitter profile slides.
[image]
[image]

as you can see in the twitter app when I open someones profile pic1 is shown and as I slide over the description of that profile is shown. I want to do something similar in my app

the concept is to show a music track with play button over it and then as i slide over I have another music track with play button over it and so on.

as much as the research I could do I came across the viewpager class but the documentation is not well written for new comers.

how do I proceed with this, just a basic idea to push me ahead?
thanks!

Comment: looking for naviagation drawer? http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379261/make-carousel-with-viewflipper-or-viewpager

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use horizontal scrollview for sliding and use gestureDetector to detect left/right swipe.

Answer (score 0):

Either Use ViewPager for that.It is a specifically use for sliding pages without scrolling.

Use  [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) link